Why does Request.build_absolute_uri lead to localhost instead of the real domain?
I have a website deployed on Nginx and built on Django.
The Request.build_absolute_uri link there for some reason leads not to the real domain and ip which is attached to it, but to localhost:8080 of Waitress/gunicorn on which the app is running. Why?
I tried Request.build_absolute_uri and request._current_scheme_host both lead to the localhost.
Now, temporarily I just use the direct path like "https://example.com", but it is not a very convinient decision.
Could you please let me know how to solve it?

After some time I've figured out that passing request all around just to build full urls was messy, I've reimplemented the function used to build absolute url. You just set HOSTNAME in settings to different hostname per environment.
def build_base_uri():
    return getattr(settings, "USED_PROTOCOL", "http://") + getattr(settings, "HOSTNAME", "localhost")


def build_absolute_url(url):
    return build_base_uri() + url


If you want to stick with request's methods, I've studied it's source code and here is how it determines the host which will be used in the uri. (assuming you don't have DEBUG and your ALLOWED_HOSTS are properly set)
class HttpRequest:
    ...

    def _get_raw_host(self):
        """
        Return the HTTP host using the environment or request headers. Skip
        allowed hosts protection, so may return an insecure host.
        """
        # We try three options, in order of decreasing preference.
        if settings.USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST and (
                'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' in self.META):
            host = self.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
        elif 'HTTP_HOST' in self.META:
            host = self.META['HTTP_HOST']
        else:
            # Reconstruct the host using the algorithm from PEP 333.
            host = self.META['SERVER_NAME']
            server_port = self.get_port()
            if server_port != ('443' if self.is_secure() else '80'):
                host = '%s:%s' % (host, server_port)
        return host

according to this, check in the view these headers HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST or HTTP_HOST or SERVER_NAME. If these headers are for some reason contain localhost or are not present, you may investigate the issue in the nginx configuration about passing the headers down.

Thank you very much for the very detailed instruction. I very appreciate your help. Following your tips I will try to fix this problem asap.
